# Dead keys maps missing in certain programs only

Tags: x11, key-mapping, dead-keys

I cannot use <kbd>^</kbd> with certain programs. I'm working in KDE on OpenSUSE 13.1 64b.

<kbd>^</kbd> works as a dead key in Konsole, Firefox, Chrome, Gvim.

<kbd>^</kbd> has no effect (pressing <kbd>^</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> just inserts `a`) in Xterm, Emacs, Opera, Libreoffice.

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-keytable.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "LocalKeyboard"
   MatchIsKeyboard "on"
   Option   "XkbLayout" "ch"
   Option   "XkbVariant"   "fr"
EndSection
```

**UPDATE**

In answer to Gilles' comment, I post `xdv` output for `^`

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x25e, subw 0x0, time 19371288, (-553,369), root:(297,392),
    state 0x10, keycode 21 (keysym 0xfe52, dead_circumflex), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (5e) "^"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's the output of `env | grep IM`

```
QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
CACHESTALLTIME=12
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
QT_IM_SWITCHER=imsw-multi
```

**EDIT 3**

I have solved the problem for emacs gui adding the line in .emacs:

```
(load-library "iso-transl")
```

Comment: @gilles In xterm  I get `ae`. In konsole I get `âe`. When I press `^` twice, I get `ae` and `^ae` respectively.

Comment: `showkey` is too low-level to get useful information here. Run the program `xev` from a terminal and press `^`. Copy-paste the paragraph that begins with `KeyPress event` for pressing `^`. Do other dead keys work?

Comment: @Gilles I have updted my post with `xdev` output

Comment: Hmmm. The key is correct. Do you have an input method set up? I have no idea where it might be configured. What does `env | grep IM` show (if anything)?

Comment: @Gilles I updated my post with the requested ouput