# Which are the files and applications that manage keyboard and dead keys configuration in KDE?

Tags: kde, keyboard, dead-keys

I´m using kubuntu 15.04 and started to have a problem with dead keys. Some applications (like Kate, Libreoffice Writer) work as expected with the keyboard but others (like Firefox, Emacs) don´t. The actual problem is that instead of getting an accented vowel (e. g. "á") I get two separated characters ("´a").

I use a spanish dvorak distribution, but I tried also with standard spanish and latinamerican, and it´s the same.

Which are the files and applications that manage the keyboard related configuration in KDE? How can I solve this problem?

---

Edit: this might be a dupplicate question of [Dead keys map missing in certain programs only](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165538/dead-keys-maps-missing-in-certain-programs-only)